# XCode 14 - Minimum deployment target for SPM package

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I am actually compiling for macOS 10.12, as stated. I import the Reachability.swift package, that is compatible down to 10.9. No minimum version is indicated within the Package.swift file. However, I get this error while compiling :

> Compiling for macOS 10.12, but module 'Reachability' has a minimum
> deployment target of macOS 10.13

It happens since I updated to XCode 14, with version 13, there was no problem.
If I specify the minimum version in the Package.swift of Reachability `platforms:[.macOS(.v10_10)],`, I clean all the caches, I get the same problem.

I could probably upgrade deployment target to 10.13 (same computer compatibility) or simply include the Reachability.swift file in my code, but I would rather that it works...

[EDIT] Note : other packages, like AppCenter, do not have the same problem… which is weird.

[EDIT 2] With the release of XCode 14.1, the problem remains the same.

Do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: Xcode 14.1 will increase minimum supported version to 10.13 anyways. It might be an SPM issue that they didn't anticipate Xcode 14 to ship with macOS 12 SDK while the betas all had macOS 13 SDK.

Comment: I forgot to mention that other packages, like AppCenter, do not have the same problem… which is weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem: Using AppCenter is OK, but the reachability throws an error.

Here is what I found and maybe this is the root cause:

1. Make Reachability a local SPM, and modify its swift-tool-version settings and platform settings to align with AppCenter.

   [image: SPM Modification]
2. Then if you click into the `.v10_12` MacOSVersion, you will find os versions lower than 10.13 has all been marked as unsupported

[image: 10.13 below is unsupported now]

3. If you head to the built files, test it with `otool`, you will find the built product's minimum supported version matches with the above description:
   [image]
   So even if you specify the minimum support version to `10.12`, the build tools will still target `10.13`.
4. If you check `LC_MIN_VERSION_MACOSX` on `AppCenter`. It is also targeting `10.13` instead of `10.12` in its package.swift file.
5. But why Xcode accepts `AppCenter` and raise an error for `Reachability`?

[image]

Check the build log below. You will find it in the `emitting module` stage, the build system is using `swift-frontend` to embed those 3rd party dependencies. So I guess since the AppCenter is written in objective C.

The checking minimum os version behavior of `swift-frontend` is different between OC Dependency "AppCenter" and Swift Dependency "Reachability."

[image]

Comment: So it means that with Xcode 14.1, there is no mean to compile for 10.12 anymore ? I am really disappointed.

Comment: I see your edit about the latest 14.1. I'm afraid so.